# Emberjs + Rails - TypeError: Cannot call method 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined (Unable to POST to Rails DB)

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-rails

I am trying to POST a new record into Rails db with Emberjs and ember-data; however I am getting the following error:

> TypeError {} "Cannot call method 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined"

I have been following the example of https://github.com/dgeb/ember_data_example and tried to build my own app using the same concept as per the example. Not to mention, I have used the *debugger;* within my controller and when I hit *this.get('preLoadedData')* in the console, it manage to fetch my input into the form. However, the issue is that I cannot POST the user input into Rails DB.

The codes are:

#### Store

```
DS.RESTAdapter.configure("plurals", {"company_category": "company_categories"});
  App.Adapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    bulkCommit: false
});

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 12,
  adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create()
});
```

#### Model

```
App.CompanyCategory = DS.Model.extend({
    category:   DS.attr("string")
});
```

#### Controller

```
App.CompanyCategoriesNewController = Em.ObjectController.extend({

    startEditing: function() {
        this.transaction = this.get('store').transaction();
        this.set('model', this.transaction.createRecord(App.CompanyCategory, {}));
    },

    save: function() {
        this.transaction.commit();
        this.transaction = null;
    }
});
```

Under rails controller:-

```
def create
    @category = CompanyCategory.new(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @category.save
        format.json { render json: @category, status: :created, location: @category }
      else
        format.json { render json: @category.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity}
      end
    end
  end
```

#### Router

```
App.CompanyCategoriesNewRoute = Em.Route.extend({
   model: function() {
       return null;
   },

   setupController: function(controller) {
       this._super.apply(this,arguments);
       controller.startEditing();
   }
});
```

And my JSON output when I called *App.CompanyCategory.find();* is:

```
{
   "company_categories":[
           {"id":1,"category":"Financial Services"},
           {"id":2,"category":"Trade Services"}
   ]
}
```

May I know what have I been doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you still looking for answers to this question or have you moved on?

Comment: I definitely am still looking for it =)

Comment: why are you doing this.transaction = null ?

Comment: @Hrishi, I thought of setting it to null once commit is performed so that the previous saved data doesn't get commit twice in the event save function is being called again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things here, it is considered bad practice to have controller set its own model. Instead, its the job of the router to provide a model to the controller.
So according to the ember way of doing things, you should be doing:

```
App.CompanyCategoriesNewRoute = Em.Route.extend({
   model: function() {
    return this.get('store').createRecord(App.CompanyCategory, {});
   },

  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.set('content', model);
  }
});

App.CompanyCategoriesNewController = Em.ObjectController.extend({


    startEditing: function() {
       this.set('transaction', this.get('store').transaction());
       this.get('transaction').add(this.get('model'));
   },

   save: function() {
     this.get('transaction').commit();
  }
```

});

Comment: It would help if you could show us the handlebars as well.